# Android Navigational Drawer with Textviews, Buttons

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a personal details page where the user can view and change his/her personal details. I followed a tutorial and created a Navigational Drawer which loads a ListView. The thing is that i need to add a few TextViews and 1 button but no matter where i put them in the xml, they keep showing outside the drawer, messing up the whole layout. Any help? Thanks for your time everyone!!!

GuestMain.java

```js
public class GuestMain extends Activity {
 
 /////////NAVIGATIONA LDRAWER///////
 String[] info;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView dList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ///////////////////////////////////
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        ////////////////////////////////////////NAVIGATIONAL DRAWER//////////////////////////////////////////////
  info = new String[]{"Full Name","Phone Number","Email","Address","Country","City"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,info);
        dList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dList.setSelector(android.R.color.darker_gray);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 }
```

activity_guest_main.xml

```js
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    
    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.domotel.GuestMain" >
    
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iconback"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_back"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#e5b53a" />
    
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iconuser"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_back"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_user"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#e5b53a" />
    </RelativeLayout>

  <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/content_frame"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  
  <ListView
   android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
   android:layout_width="240dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   android:dividerHeight="0dp"
   android:background="#d9ffffff"/>
   <!-- 85% Opacity -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand what you are trying to do, but here is the way that I understand what your saying. You want to have the ability to edit items inside the drawer and then have the changes reflected outside. Don't really think that this is what the drawer was designed for. But in order to have the text boxes inside the drawer with the strings you could create another xml layout file with the list view containing a string and a text box. Then in place of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 you would use your drawer_layout from your xml layout file

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_layout, R.id.text_field, info)

Then you need to handle the text and layout from within the drawer